# ADF - ViewObject getRowAtRangeIndex returns null even though row count is 300

Tags: jdbc, oracle-adf

getRowAtRangeIndex is returning null when I pass in for example 14.  However, if I check the rows it says there's 300.  I have the ViewObject return all rows automatically.  If I run this same method in a click listener, it has no issues.  It's only when I'm trying to pre-populate a table.  Any ideas?

Thanks, Graeme

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more and also tell your adf version? when and how are you calling getRowAtRangeIndex?

Comment: Latest version of ADF 12.2.1.2.0.  I'm trying to call it when before the page comes up so I can populate a table.  Code  <code>RowSetIterator rowSetParameterDetailIterator =         ParameterDepartmentVOImpl parameterDepartmentVOIm = applicationModule.findViewObject("ParameterDepartmentVO1");
        parameterDepartmentVOImpl.executeQuery();
        while (rowSetParameterDetailIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowSetParameterDetailIterator.next();
            Row selectedRow = parameterDepartmentVOImpl.getRowAtRangeIndex(Integer.valueOf(row.getAttribute("Dept"));</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do a server event from the client, then it loaded in the correct time.  Used this to solve it:

http://killm3-adf.blogspot.com/2014/08/calling-java-method-on-page-load.html

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was calling this method for a value change listener. The issue was that the Range size was set to 10 and the row I was trying to fetch is 187. Even though the rowCount is greater than the index, range size is less than the index.

Fixed this issue by setting range size as -1 for the corresponding viewobject iterator in the pagedef.